# Java:RequestMapping match unlimited path to a specific jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

For example ,I want to create a 404 page with 2 different template ,one is pc,another is mobile.and I am using user-agent  to calculate it.I am using * to match all url except the normal url my site own.

but it can only match like:
www.abc.com/notfound1

it can not match www.abc.com/notfound1/notfound2,etc...

I want to match the url path controller not have,how to do it,thanks.

the point of view is below ,I want to using a word to describe it,and **any** means * symbol:

> @RequestMapping(value = "any", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>
> @RequestMapping(value = "any/any", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>
> @RequestMapping(value = "any/any/any", method = RequestMethod.GET)

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView notfound() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    String useragent = servletRequest.getHeader("user-agent");
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(useragent)) {
        boolean isMobile = CheckMobile.check(useragent);
        if (isMobile) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("errormobile");
        }
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`@RequestMapping(value={"/notfound1/notfound2", "/notfound3", "/notfound4"})`

OR

You can control the view with JS depends on device resolution.
Still i don't know what exactly you want to do.